# How to do cascading in infopath without connecting any external data source?

Tags: infopath, cascading

I have two drop down in infopath form one for country and another one for state, according country need to show state in state drop-down and data need to bind from infopath itself(not from SharePoint or excel).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an XML file on a way like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <data>
    <item Name="Country1" State="State1" />
    <item Name="Country1" State="State2" />
    <item Name="Country1" State="State3" />
    <item Name="Country2" State="State4" />
    <item Name="Country2" State="State5" />
    <item Name="Country2" State="State6" />
</data>
```

Save as "data.xml"

1. Then in your infopath form add data connection an refer to this XML data file
2. Create 1 dropdown "Country" choose "Get choices from an external data source" and choose the xml data connection (check "Show only entries with unique display names")
3. Set @Name as Value and Display Name.
4. Then 2nd dropdown create "State". Also set the data source as above of the dropdown and now choose the @State value as Value and Display Name.
5. Then press on the icon "Select Xpath" at the end of "Entries" line.
6. There you choose "Filter Data". Choose "Add". Set "Name" *is equal to the* "Country" field.